# chekpointing dataframe to disk in a long process when no loop is involved

Tags: r

I have a long process in R and I want to save the working result dataframe every "t" time.

There's no loop involved, so you cannot use counter or iterator to explicit a condition to write to disk.

There's a lot of cirsumstances you could need to preserve the "on progress data frame" to disk, for instance, taking a big dataset of locations (Street + City + Zip code) you try to get Lat/Lon using ggmap package

```
    df<- mutate_geocode(long.data, location)
....long time.....
    write.table(df, file = "my_result.csv")
```

The result dataframe is only written to disk at the end of process.
The issue is, sometimes my laptop freezes and Google Maps limit is 2.500 querys per day, so my work is lost because it's not saved to disk. You have to start again all process from scratch.

is a very generic question, so no sample data is provided.

is there any way in R of checkpointing my work to disk if no loop is involved?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess if splitting your data into smaller data frames of , let's say, 100 rows and looping through all of them but saving to disk for every one and stacking all at the end?

Comment: I'd rather like to keep one big df. Your trick came to mind but not very pretty if I may say